# WordPress CF7 validation Error on "Rich Text Editor" first Time Submit

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, rich-text-editor, validationerror

I used "Rick Text Editor" in WordPress Contact Form 7, CF7 validation does not work on the first submission and validation works only on the second submission. But verification works correctly in other input fields.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXQRR.jpg)

Comment: How did you use the Rich Text Editor?  Without providing any of your custom code, nobody can help you.  If you're looking for plugin support, this is not the right place for that.

Comment: How are you displaying the text editor?  Did you use custom code or are you using a plugin for this?